# How to delete items from combo box which is connected to database and automatically refresh it?

Tags: vb.net, combobox, visual-studio-2019

I'm having a little trouble here. 
What I'm trying to do here is to delete an item in the combo box which is connected to the database and after deleting, it automatically refreshes the contents of the combo box.

```
        Dim cons As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb")

        Using cons


            With cmd
                .Connection = cons
                .CommandText = "DELETE FROM  Judges Where Fullname = @FullName"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", cmbJudges.SelectedItem.ToString)
                .Connection.Open()
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
                .Connection.Close()

                MessageBox.Show("RECORD HAS BEEN DELETED", "DELETE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)


                txtFullNameJudge.Text = Nothing
                txtContactJudge.Text = Nothing
                txtUserNameJudge.Text = Nothing
                txtPasswordJudge.Text = Nothing
                cmbJudges.Text = ""

            End With
        End Using
```

It is deleting a record but it doesn't refresh the contents of the combo box and then I can't delete another data. It seems that I can only delete a single data. Then I need to re-run the program so before the delete take effect.

Comment: I have answered this question on another site. The most correct solution is to completely ditch what you're doing, making this question moot. You should not be directly modifying the database and then expecting your `ComboBox` to update automatically or manually. What you should be doing is populating a `DataTable` and binding that to the `ComboBox`, then modifying that `DataTable` first and saving those changes to the database. The `ComboBox` will update automatically when the `DataTable` bound to it is modified.

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided. But what I want to do is to do this by not using binding. I want to write the code so I can see myself the importance of ado.net and how to use it effectively.

Comment: That is misguided. ADO.NET and data-binding are unrelated, although they are often both used together, as they should be. I told you that you should be using a data adapter to retrieve data into a `DataTable` and save changes back to the database. That's ADO.NET. You are most likely under the false impression that data-binding means adding a `DataSet` to a form in the designer. That is one way to do it but certainly not the only way and not the way that I was necessarily suggesting. Even with fully separate data access, business logic and presentation layers, you should still use data-binding.

Comment: Wow, That's great info. What you said is true. I thought working with data-binding is about working with a designer. Thank you for clarifying things. I just want to clarify somethings. @Mary said that using an adapter requires a primary key? Can you please expand it a little more?

Comment: My delete command above don't have a primary key. @Mary is correct the field `FullName` does not have a primary key so I can't use a data adapter? Is that correct? Anyway, thank you for your last comment it gives me additional info.

Comment: If you are using a `FullName` value from a `ComboBox` to identify the record to delete then you are using a value that you previously retrieved from the database. If you can retrieve that value from the database, why can't you get the primary key value as well? You almost certainly should be. You're trying to solve a problem that you have created in the first place. If you do it right to begin with then there's no problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help but it seems that your answer just makes me more confused about these things. If you're pissed off by my questions I'm sorry. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now like what I wanted. Whenever I delete a data via the combobox it deletes it and then reloads the combobox with the values from `FullName` field. @Mary and @jmcilhinney Thanks for all the help.

here is the WORKING CODE for my DELETE BUTTON:

```
 Private Sub btnJudgeDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnJudgeDelete.Click


        Using cons As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(conSTR)
            Using com As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Judges WHERE FullName = @FullName")
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", cmbJudges.Text)
                com.Connection = cons
                cons.Open()
                com.ExecuteNonQuery()

                MessageBox.Show("DATA HAS BEEN DELETED")
            End Using
        End Using


        cmbJudges.Text = ""
        txtFullNameJudge.Text = Nothing
        txtContactJudge.Text = Nothing
        txtUserNameJudge.Text = Nothing
        txtPasswordJudge.Text = Nothing
        cmbJudges.Items.Clear()

        Dim rd As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(conSTR),
            cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select FullName From Judges", cn)
            cn.Open()
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While rd.Read
                cmbJudges.Items.Add(rd.Item(0))
            End While
            rd.Close()
        End Using



    End Sub
```

Comment: May I know the reason why my earlier answer was deleted? @Martijn Pieters.

Comment: It was deleted because it looked like you were asking a follow up question. It wasn't clear enough that this post is **the answer** to your question. Usually when people address other users in their answers and ask follow up questions it means that they didn't really post a solution, but they just wanted to comment on other posts. I would advise to remove the follow up question from your answer and stick only to the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

The first method is more code but the second method, which I think is closer to what was suggested in comments by @jmcilhinney, might pose a problem. I think the `DataAdapte`r requires a primary key to be part of the Select. If `FullName` is not the primary key of the Judges table, this method might not work.

You may wish to make `dt` (the `Datatable`) a Form level variable so you don't have to extract and cast it from the `.DataSource` property. It will then be available to both the method where you fill the combo and the method where you delete a Judge. Be sure to delete the local variables if you do this.

```
Private Sub FillJudgesCombo()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select FullName From Judges")
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    cmbJudges.DisplayMember = "FullName"
    cmbJudges.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteJudge1()
    'I stored this in a local variable because we are using it more tha once in this method
    Dim NameToDelete = cmbJudges.Text
    'To update the database
    Using cons As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM  Judges Where Fullname = @FullName", cons)
        'had to guess at the datatype and field size - check your database
        'The Add method is much preferred to the .AddWithValue
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FullName", OleDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = NameToDelete
        cons.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    'To update the combo box by editing DataTable
    Dim dt = DirectCast(ComboBox1.DataSource, DataTable)
    'This line uses and interpolated string indicated by the $ preceding the string.
    'This allows to insearch a variable in place in the string surronded by braces.
    Dim dr = dt.Select($"FullName = {NameToDelete}")
    dr(0).Delete()
    dt.AcceptChanges()
    ResetTextBoxesAndCombo()
    MessageBox.Show("RECORD HAS BEEN DELETED", "DELETE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub

Private Sub ResetTextBoxesAndCombo()
    'Offloaded this because it really has nothing to do with deleting a judge.
    txtFullNameJudge.Text = Nothing
    txtContactJudge.Text = Nothing
    txtUserNameJudge.Text = Nothing
    txtPasswordJudge.Text = Nothing
    cmbJudges.SelectedIndex = -1
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteJudge2()
    Dim NameToDelete = cmdJudges.Text
    Dim dt = DirectCast(ComboBox1.DataSource, DataTable)
    'The Select method has no idea how many rows are returned
    'so it returns an array of DataRows
    Dim dr = dt.Select($"FullName = {NameToDelete}")
    'We are only interested in the first item in the array.
    'The array should only have one element.
    dr(0).Delete()
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb"),
            da As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select FullName From PAGEANT", con)
        Dim cmdBuild As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Update(dt)
    End Using
    ResetTextBoxesAndCombo()
    MessageBox.Show("RECORD HAS BEEN DELETED", "DELETE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks for all the help. But is there any other way that has less complex coding? `FillJudgesCombo()` I tried to put this in the form load event but it doesn't retrieve data. it shows `no data found`.

Comment: I tried your `DeleteJudge1()` and NullReferenceException occurs. It says st was nothing. it's pointing to this line `Dim dr = dt.Select($"FullName = {NameToDelete}")` pardon my questions, I'm just starting my path to be a developer.

Comment: @lelouch Did you change `ComboBox1` to `cmbJudges` in `Dim dt = DirectCast(ComboBox1.DataSource, DataTable)` My mistake. I was using controls with default names to test the code. Correct line for your controls should be `Dim dt = DirectCast(cmbJudges.DataSource, DataTable)`. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, I did. I change all the labels to my own but still, the exception occurs. I can't really understand the code that you gave me, I'm sorry especially with the direct cast part.

Comment: I tried using my code for delete and adding my code from my form load event so that, after I delete it reloads the updated database just like on my form load but the problem is after I delete the data it just duplicates what's inside the combo box. So I guess It's not the proper way to do it.

Comment: @lelouch Regarding the `DirectCast` ... The way we filled the combo box was setting the `.DataSource` to the `DataTable`. That data table exists as the .DataSource property for the life of the combo box. We suck it back out and cast it back to a DataTable when we need it. We use DirectCast because we are sure it is a DataTable. I think DirectCast is a bit faster than CType because it skips some type checking.

Comment: My next question is did you load the combo box the way it shows in `FillJudgesCombo()`?

Comment: I thought my problem is just simple but I'am now overloaded with information. Thank you for all the help @Mary. Maybe I should start this all over again. I'm stuck with this for a week now.

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried to put it on the form load event to see what it does. It retrieves the  FullName field and put it in the combo box but upon the load, it shows `no data has found` but still the data is loaded to the Combobox and whenever I click on the value inside the Combobox it shows `no data has been found`

Comment: Open the Microsoft Access application. Instead of picking a database from the list choose Open. Then choose Browse. Navigate to C:\Users\athan\Documents\PAGEANT.accdb and then open. Check the table name is Judges and the field name is FullName. Make sure there is data in the table.

Comment: Change Dim dr = dt.Select($"FullName = {NameToDelete}") to Dim dr = dt.Select($"FullName = '{NameToDelete}'") That is adding single quotes around the braces { }.